# What PowerShell command would you use to create a Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, powershell, hyper-v, vhd

I've seen the following question:

> What PowerShell command would you use to create a Hyper-V virtual machine?
>
> ```
> New-VM -Name "VM Name" -MemoryStartupBytes <memory> -NewVHDSizeBytes <disk size>
> New-VM -Name "VM Name" -MemoryStartupBytes <memory> -VHDSizeBytes <disk size>
> New-VM -Name "VM Name" -MemoryStartupBytes <memory> -NewVHDXSizeBytes <disk size>
> New-VM -Name "VM Name" -MemoryStartupBytes <memory> -VHDXSizeBytes <disk size>
> ```

Apparently the option is number 1 but why is this? why not number three a vhdx?

Comment: Why does this question start with "23."?

Comment: VHDX is the new file extension and only supported on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012. Its not evident what version of Hyper-V you are using. **The other 3 commands do not even exist.** Depending on the version of Hyper-V installed on the system the correct file extension would be used automatically by default.  Since this could have been easily researched I have to issue a downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VHDX is the format of a virtual disk introduced by Windows 8/Windows Server 2012 (Hyper-V 3), but Powershell parameter for a [New-VM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848537.aspx) (*-NewVHDSizeBytes*) was not changed to *-NewVHDXSizeBytes*.

Comment: brilliant thank you very much. what a daft thing for Microsoft to do vhd and vhdx should be defined differently in the command